# VHDL Block RAM Inference

Tags: fpga, vhdl, spartan-6

I am storing a 16k constant sine table of 14 bit signed vectors in a package.

I use this package in my module to read out the array in a clocked process

But I get this warning during synthesis and my synthesis is taking a long time -

> The RAM  will be implemented on LUTs either because you have described an asynchronous read or because of currently unsupported block RAM features. If you have described an asynchronous read, making it synchronous would allow you to take advantage of available block RAM resources, for optimized device usage and improved timings. Please refer to your documentation for coding guidelines."

code in package -

```
TYPE signed_array IS ARRAY (integer RANGE <>) OF signed (DATAWIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0); 

CONSTANT SINE_TABLE_SIZE : integer := QUARTER_LENGTH+1; -- 16384+1
----sine pi/2 = 1 <=> "0111111....1" MSB is 0 because of the signed representation

CONSTANT SINE_TABLE : signed_array(0 TO SINE_TABLE_SIZE-1):= (
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.0), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*9.5873799096e-05), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000191747597311), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000287621393763), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000383495187571), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000479368977855), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000575242763732), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000671116544322), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000766990318743), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000862864086114), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.000958737845553), DATAWIDTH) ,
                    to_signed(integer((2.0**(DATAWIDTH-1)-1.0)*0.00105461159618), DATAWIDTH) ,


process(clk)
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        ctd <= ctr + 1;
    end if;
end process;

cos <= SINE_TABLE(to_integer(unsigned(ctr)));
```

Any suggestions on how to write a vhdl code in infer a block RAM instead of LUTs?

The SINE TABLE is in a package, and the process is in the main module

Comment: Can you present some code? You can set a RAM_STYLE attribute to force BlockRAM usage. I assume XST misses a read clock because BlockRAM does not support synchronous read.

Comment: I will modify the question to add code..

Comment: What you have in here is giant combinatorial block you need to synchronize your access by putting the read operation in the clocked process.

Comment: @FarhadA yes...have done it

Answer (score 3):

Move the take lookup right next to the increment so the output is registered.

That is a gigantic lookup table, though. You may want to consider using a compressed lookup table to save on the block RAM. The trade-off is you may need a couple of multipliers.

Here is an example of a pipelined, compressed sine lookup table: https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-dsp/blob/master/rtl/sine_dds_lut.v .  By default, this one has an 18 bit phase input (2^18 = 262k equivalent entries) with a 16 bit output width.  It consumes 3 block RAMs (two are 512x16 and one is 256x8) and two DSP slices.

Comment: u mean i should register cos assignment as well?

Comment: Yeah. Xilinx block RAMs want a register on the output data.  If you don't provide one, this is the error you get.  Yes, I have made this mistake many times before.

Comment: i registered the output. It still doesnt work.

Comment: i want the output to be registered based on the 2 MSBs of the counter. So I have a case statement inside the process where the output is being registered. this is a clocked process

Comment: i however saw that if i register the output inside a simple clocked process, the tool infers a block ram

Comment: You can register it again later if you need to, but it has to be registered at the same time you do the lookup for it to infer a block RAM.

Comment: It works now...I had some timing issues but now no more. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The memory read needs to be registered to be recognised as a block RAM:

```
process(clk)
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        ctr <= ctr + 1;
        cos <= SINE_TABLE(to_integer(unsigned(ctr)));
    end if;
end process;
```

I would also make `ctr` of an `integer` type - then you don't need to faff around with the conversions.

Comment: this works...but what i actually want is not a direct assignment  of "cos" but an assignment based on the 2 MSBs of the ctr to decide which quadrant of the sine signal is used. So I gave a case structure inside this clocked process, but this causes somehow the synthesis tool again not to infer the block ram

Comment: Are you trying to read both the sin and cos in the same clock cycle? If so you need to be careful to use a VHDL construct which the synthesis tool recognises as a dual-read BRAM.  Also, keep the memory-reading logic separate from the address calculating logic (in separate processes) if you are using XST - it sometimes struggles to identify RAM constructs when things are mixed together in the same process.

Comment: Thank you...that makes sense why the tool was not inferring the block RAM

Comment: I had mixed a mux inside the same clocked process as the output registration of the block RAM